# VSTest Console with Jenkins- No test is available in the provided sources

Tags: jenkins, vstest.console

While working on Selenium with C#, I used Nunit3testadapter to locate my testscripts in test explorer. I wrote the command line to execute my tests. That batch file uses VSTest.console.exe, which works fine for me.

vstest.console.exe "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Automation\TestCases\bin\Debug\TestCases.dll" /UseVsixExtensions:true /InIsolation /Logger:trx

But when I tried to create automatic build process with Jenkins and used exactly same command. It started giving me error. "No test is available in the provided sources. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again".

I have tried multiple options like:
1. Execute Windows Batch command
2. Run unit tests with VSTest.Console

If anyone has it's solution, please help me on it. Thanks in advance.

See the console log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QA4i.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced exactly the same symptoms. What helped in my case was:

1. Uninstall nUnit test adapter using Visual Studio Extensions and updates
2. Download nUnit test adapter vsix extension and store it locally
3. Use vsixinstaller command line utility to install the vsix using /admin switch, i.e:
   vsixinstaller /admin c:/temp/NUnit3TestAdapter-3.7.0.vsix

I hope it helps in your scenario as well.